# Data binding in C# codebehind

Tags: c#, xml, data-binding, code-behind

I would like to bind an Xml file with C# codebehind.
That is, instead of opening a file as shown in the below code snippet, I would like to use 
an Xml file embedded into project solution with an Xml filename.

Could you say how I can do this.

```
XmlDataProvider provider = new XmlDataProvider();

if (provider != null) 
{
  System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

  doc.Load(fileName);   
  provider.Document = doc;   
  provider.XPath = "/opml/body/outline";   
  FeedListTreeView.DataContext = provider; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have marked the file as an "embedded resource" in Visual Studio, then [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292) will show you the way to load it form your assembly.  The main thing to keep in mind is that instead of the "\" character that you normally use in the path to a file, you want to use the "." character.

if you are trying to read it from the file system, then [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548) will show you the way.